# Using com.google.android.gms.auth to pass user credentials to sign in google account

Tags: android, authentication, google-play-services, google-signin

I am trying to build an app to use com.google.android.gms.auth api for google sign.

I don't want to prompt to user for entering username and password. I want to pass the credentials using the code and sign in user directly.

Can anyone suggest a way to use this?